# How to detect if my chrome app is focussed or not?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I want to detect whether my chrome app is focussed or not. Based on the output I want to show a simple "toast" or show a `chrome.notifications.create`.

Comment: Hmm. `document.hidden` does not work, and I don't immediately see the answer in `chrome.app.window`

Comment: i want to do the same thing too. Have u found the solution?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [another answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264324/chrome-packaged-app-onblur-listener)